# entity framework ref, deref, createref

Tags: entity-framework-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what scenarios would I need to use the CREATEREF, DEREF and REF keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556589/in-what-scenarios-would-i-need-to-use-the-createref-deref-and-ref-keywords)

I'm not asking what are ref, deref, and createref in entity framework. but the question is what are the prupose and benefit of ref, deref, and createref in entity framework?

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to know.... I can't find any scenarios that show where this would be useful/required...